# Indy 10 OpenSSL load library error on MacOS

Tags: macos, delphi, openssl, indy, indy10

I'm using Delphi Alexandria on Windows 11 to develop a MacOS application in FMX.

I'm trying to use OpenSSl; I have `libssl.1.0.0.dylib` and `libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib` in the directory.

But I always have an error:

> can't load ssl library

So I'm debugging, and notice that in the `IdGlobal` unit, the `HackLoad()` function returns 0:

```pascal
function HackLoad(const ALibName : String; const ALibVersions : array of String) : TIdLibHandle;
var
  i : Integer;

  function LoadLibVer(const ALibVer: string): TIdLibHandle;
  var
    FileName: string;
  begin
    FileName := HackLoadFileName(ALibName, ALibVer);

    {$IFDEF USE_SAFELOADLIBRARY}
    Result := SafeLoadLibrary(FileName);
    {$ELSE}

    // ** here result is not equal to 0 **


    // **BUT here, this method brings the result to 0 **
    {$IFDEF USE_INVALIDATE_MOD_CACHE}
    InvalidateModuleCache;   
    {$ENDIF}
  end;
```

I tested several libraries and debugging the code.